# Removing NULs from bytearray / blobColumn c#

Tags: c#, ssis, arrays

My goal is to output a long string into a BlobColumn (Text) in SSIS script component and here's the code to do it.

```
byte[] blobdata = GetBytes(notes.Substring(0, (notes.Length < 16000 ? notes.Length : 16000)));
blobdata = blobdata.SkipWhile(x => x == 0).ToArray(); //Remove the nulls?
Row.SCNotes.AddBlobData(blobdata);
```

When I open the file in notepad++ that I've output this field to, it looks like this

original string: abc

output: a[nul]b[nul]c[nul]

Am I doing anything wrong with the code? How can I not output the nulls?

Comment: Help me understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to write the contents of a blob field out of a database and into a file? Are you trying to import binary data into the database? Where is the `notes` data coming from?

Comment: You can assume notes is a very large string that is derived from a field from the source file. And then trying to insert it into a new Text output column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Strings in C# are stored as utf16 which causes this issue

```
byte[] blobdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strNotes);
```

solved it by converting to utf8 which removed the nulls in between each character.